# MVC 4 RouteConfig

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have MVC 4 Web Project and I wrote this code in RouteConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "home", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Course",
            "{controller}/{courseId}",
            new { action = "index" }
       );

    }
```

And I want to link **[site-root]/course/15** but not working (HTTP 404 Error).
How can i solve this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as "Course" is the type of resource you're trying to set up, I'd create a CourseController with e.g. an Index action and set up in RouteConfig like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Course",
            "course/{courseId}",
            new { action = "Index", controller="Course" }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use the second MapRoute.
Try creating an Action named Course at your HomeController. For example :

```
   public ActionResult Course(string id) {
      //implementation
   }
```

This should work.